# Can I make CloudFlare alias any /* request to a specific page?

Tags: cdn, cloudflare

I would like to serve any `www.domain.com/*` route with a specific static HTML page in my server. Is it possible to do this at a CDN level, for example using CloudFlare?

For example:

`www.domain.com/12934`, `www.domain.com/abc/283`, `www.domain.com` all these three render the same static page in `www.domain.com/index.html`

Comment: Can you edit this to provide an example of what you're wanting to do so it's clearer to others?

Comment: The more common way to do this is to simply add a `301` redirect rule in the config file of your origin server, however it might be possible to do this using a _wildcard_ and Page Rules. See the CloudFlare docs on this [here](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172286-How-do-I-do-url-forwarding-with-CloudFlare-) and [here](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168306-Is-there-a-tutorial-for-Page-Rules-).

Comment: Thanks dan, a redirect is different than an alias though. I would like to keep the URL and not redirect to a different URL.

Comment: In that case, follow the links I provided for Page Rules (as per Damon from CloudFlare answered too).

Answer (score 1):

It would have to be a PageRule redirect of some sort via CloudFlare, unfortunately.